How to combine port forwarding and NAT/PAT on Cisco router?
I have a problem, that I cannot bring together working PAT and Port forwarding on a Cisco router.
Here is my topology:

Explanation to topology:
Start connection sourced by 192.168.1.1 with destination port 1234 and destination ip address 192.168.1.2 on f1/0. Then router forwards connection to destination ip address 192.168.2.2 and destination port 5678 out of f0/0. When forwarding the packet out of f0/0 to ip address 192.168.2.2 and destination port 5678, here be careful, then with source ip address of f0/0 192.168.2.1.
Here is my config:
# ip nat outside source static tcp 192.168.1.2 1234 192.168.2.2 5678
# ip access-list standard ACL-NAT-CAPABLE
# permit 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255
# ip nat inside source list ACL-NAT-CAPABLE int f0/0 overload
# int f1/0
# ip nat inside
# int f0/0
# ip nat outside

Can someone explain why such a solution is not working? Or can someone please give me a config solution to the given problem?

Has any answer solved your question? Then please accept it or your question will keep popping up here forever. Please also consider voting for useful answers.

A PAT and Static NAT (Port Forwarding) can coexist and are commonly used together in many network configurations.
Port forwarding is a type of NAT called Static NAT. For port forwarding you need the internal host IP, the internal port and the external port. In this case the internal host is 192.168.1.1, internal port is 1234 and the external port is 5678
Your Objectives are to:

Implement PAT for outbound traffic from the inside network Set up
Port forwarding for inbound traffic to reach H1 on a specific port

Do the configurations as follow:
! Configure interfaces
interface F1/0
 ip address 192.168.1.2 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside

interface F0/0
 ip address 192.168.2.1 255.255.255.0
 ip nat outside

! Define ACL for PAT
ip access-list standard NAT-ACL
 permit 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255

! Configure PAT
ip nat inside source list NAT-ACL interface F0/0 overload

! Configure port forwarding
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.1.1 1234 interface F0/0 5678

When testing it from the outside network by using telnet for example , you have to do as follow, (make sure some application is running on port 1234 on H1):
telnet 192.168.2.1 5678


Hi Khaalidi, you reverted my topology, but to avoid confusion let us stick now with your version.
Look: What you are proposing is, you initiate a connection from 192.168.2.2 to 192.168.2.1 5678 that is forwarded to 192.168.1.1 1234, but that still ends up with source address of 192.168.2.2. Have a closer look at my topology, because if you wanted to make it right, you should make a second NAT on F1/0 so the connection reaches 192.168.1.1 1234 with source address 192.168.1.2. Can you still help me?

It is not reversed ok, Since you defined ACL for 192.168.1.0/24 network, that means that is the internal network, and those address are to translated by the PAT.
192.168.2.0/24 is the external network to which the internal network is not routable,  if we explicitly allow a service from outside , we have to do that with a Static NAT (Port Forwarding).

you are right, sorry for this. Could you check if this config is working for you? Let us say on a 7200 or CSR1000V in GNS3? Because it is not working for me. Could it be, because you cannot NAT twice the same connection?
